# How to create table using GridView like this

Tags: android

How to create table using GridView like this:

[image: example]

I mean:

```
1st column - 2 rows;
2nd column - 1 row;
3rd column - 2 rows;
.... and so on
```

Comment: So you guys want a user banned because he's using an image upload service with tons of adult ads? Instead of going on a flagging spree one of you could just have uploaded the actual image to a different host and edited the question accordingly. @unkorix: Consider using imgur the next time - or any other host that does not serve that many ads, especially not adult ones.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I don't notice any adult images. Perhaps AdBlock App in my browser block it. I'll check twice for any adult content before post images next time.

Comment: Any replys for my question? Or any thoughts how to organise such tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom adapter for the gridview.

Suppose that each cell in your grid was to contain a button, so you would need some list

```
ArrayList<Button> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Your GridView is going to have 7 columns which you would need to specify in the your layout xml file

```
android:numColumns="5"
```

Your adapter class is going to check the list and see what cell is being instantiated. If it's the correct cell, then modify it.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listOfButtons.size();
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return true;
    // return true for clickable, false for not
}

public Button getItem(int position) {
    return listOfButtons.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listOfButtons.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button b;

        //Here is where you check to see if it's the correct cell
        //You can use the methods declared above to check
        //say i wanted every even item to be 1 cell

        if (position % 2 = 0)
            b.setHeight(100);//however high two columns are

        /*you'd also need to make the other button that's 
         * being overlapped invisible. This requires that 
         * you know what position it's going to be in. 
         * Using the same eample with 7 columns, 
         * position 8, 10, 12 and 14 will be overlapped so 
         * you can do something like*/
        if (position == 8 || position == 10 || 
            position ==12 || position ==14)
        {
            b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return b;
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            b.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        } else {
            b = (Button) convertView;
        }

        //Set properties of each
        return b;
    }
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. That's not exactly what I want, but I try to use this idea.

Comment: What exactly is it that you're looking for?

Comment: There could be 30 columns, so an app will work very slowly with so many buttons

Comment: Well I used buttons as a place holder. But if you want an empty table like the one in the picture that is going to be created dynamically with x number of rows and columns, then you'll probably want to look into using a tableLayout instead of a gridView. Then you can alter the tableRow according to whatever specifications you need.